# How to wait for a method to return a value? Asynchronous or synchronous

Tags: java, swing, rmi

I have a Java swing app. The login page is calling a method to a server and if the authentication is true the home page will appear.
The problem I'm facing is the the home page is not appearing after the login.
I think it's because  of large response time of the remote method call.

Here is my code.

```
Login l=(Login) Naming.lookup("rmi://xxxx/yyyy");
if(l.validate(uname,pass).equals("success"))
 {
 l.login();//here login will make some registry entry in the server and taking more time
        HomePage h=new HomePage();
        h.setvisible(true);

 }
```

The home page is not appearing.

Comment: and very funny thing is the program is running fine in ecplise but when i am building a jar its not working. may be ecplise has some different method of execution of thread

Comment: then how will it be  syncronized(this){if(l.validate(uname,pass).equals("success")){l.login();HomePage h=new HomePage();h.setvisible(true);}}

Comment: when u run via eclipse does home page occurs?

Comment: yes it appears.what kind of bug it has

Comment: I don't understand how using `synchronized` would help you (make sure you spell it correctly).  Maybe either the lookup or the login is failing and producing an exception, which would stop the home page from showing up. Check your logs to see if there's any kind of stack trace.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work as a jar? What errors are there? Sounds like you didn't export something correctly

Comment: i have used JOptionPane.showmessage(null,exp.toString()); everywhere no error i found. even i have used such dialog within the initcomponent() of home page. what i found is the initcomponent() is not executed fully as the last dialog at the end of initcomponent is not shown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what that `Naming` or `Login` class looks like, but I'll assume you can edit it to use async callbacks, i.e. an interface.

```
public class Login {

    // Interface callback here
    public interface OnLoginListener {
        void onSuccess(String username);
        void onError(String message);
    }

    // Added as a parameter here
    public void validate(String uname, String pass, OnLoginListener callback) {
        // TODO: However you did this, it should be a blocking call
        String response = tryLogin(uname, pass); 

        boolean errorCondition = false; // TODO: Implement
        if (errorCondition && callback != null) {
            callback.onError("Login failed");
            return;
        }

        if (response.equals("success") && callback != null) {
            callback.onSuccess(uname);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in your other code, this is how you "wait"

```
final Login l=(Login) Naming.lookup("rmi://xxxx/yyyy");

// Passed in to run asynchronously based on internal method behavior
l.validate(uname,pass, new Login.OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String username) {
        l.login();
        HomePage h=new HomePage();
        h.setvisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message) {
        System.err.println(message);
    }

});
```

Comment: you should explain your code instead of just dumping an answer

Comment: Not sure what more there is to explain than the comments I added

Comment: can i use such interface in a remote call or will it throws some rmi.stub error

Comment: You define your own interface... Why would it throw an error if you don't make it do so?

Comment: it has not worked but i have used this callback technique in my project for different use. the info was usefull

Comment: This won't work at all. `LoginListener` isn't `Serializable`, so it can't be passed as an argument of a remote method. And it cannot possibly work *as required* unless `LoginListener` extends `Remote` and is instantiated as an exported remote object: otherwise the callback will execute at the server. NB `Naming` is part of the JRE, and (2) `Login` is a remote interface, not a class.

Comment: So I'm being downvoted for not knowing the internals of the RMI classes? Fine

Comment: You're being adversely commented on for (a) not knowing that `java.rmi.Naming` exists, (b) apparently not even recognizing this as an RMI question, and (c) not providing a solution that will work in an RMI context.

Comment: Me too. He states in a comment above that it doesn't work. Baffling really.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here apepars to be that you are executing networking code on the AWT event thread. The home page *will* eventually appear, but meanwhile your GUI has been frozen. Do the RMI stuff in a separate thread.

Comment: @programmer I'm not a vote hound but it's curious that you accepted an answer that doesn't work.